# Averaging difference of two consective rows in column 3 and doing this after every 5 columns Excel

Tags: excel, average

I want to find the average values of difference of two consective rows (like C2-c1). Also i want to repeat this operation after every fifth column. Technically
repeat for every fifth column( average (succeeding row- preceeding row)).   average value should be represented in another row or column.

Comment: Some data and expected results might be helpful. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In `column D` use the formula,

`=IF(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,C2-C1,"")`

This would give the difference for every 5th row. Then use the below formula to find average,

`=AVERAGE(D:D)`

Note:- since the formula contains `ROW()` function, you have to start from `row 1` for the formula to work. If not alter the formula accordingly